# Using moment.js to find the index of an object matching today's date

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, lodash

I am trying to find the index of an object in an array that contains a timestamp that matches the  current date. Today is the 27th, so based off of my dataset, it should return the first index. I have tried two solutions, neither of which work for different reasons. I am open to using a solution to either method.

I have tried using an exact string match.

```
const index = _.findIndex(data, function(day) { 
   return day.timestampUtc === moment().startOf('day').toISOString() })
```

The above does not work because it is trying to match `2021-01-27T00:00:00Z` to `2021-01-27T06:00:00.000Z` which never catches because it would return undefined.

I have also tried

```
const index = _.findIndex(data, function(day) { 
   return moment(day.timestampUtc).day() === moment().day() }) //should return 1, but returns 2
```

This one didn't work because using `moment(day.timestampUtc)` would evaluate it to the day before due to timezone offset, so my returned index would be one too high because it evaluates against one day early.

data

```
[{
  timestampUtc: "2021-01-26T00:00:00Z"
  weatherCodeType: "FLURRIES"
 },
 {
  timestampUtc: "2021-01-27T00:00:00Z"
  weatherCodeType: "RAIN"
 }, //I want this one
{
  timestampUtc: "2021-01-28T00:00:00Z"
  weatherCodeType: "SNOW"
 },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set time to 0 and i think it's better to compare the values, not the strings:

```
index = _.findIndex(data, (day) => {
  var today = moment().utc()
  today.set({ hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 })
  return moment.utc(day.timestampUtc).valueOf() === today.valueOf()
})
```